# How does the downcast logic in pd.to_numeric decide when to downcast from Float64 to Float32?

Tags: pandas, downcast

I am trying to understand the logic behind pd.to_numeric float downcasting. I'm looking for the specific condition(s) that are used.

I was hoping / expecting that it would preserve the uniqueness of the values, but in my example, it does not.

The [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) do not explain the logic for any of the downcasting options: float, integer and unsigned. I would love to understand them all.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
s = pd.Series(np.random.uniform(0, 1, 100_000), dtype="Float64")
s_float32 = pd.to_numeric(s, downcast="float")
print(s_float32.dtype)
print(s_float32.nunique() == s.nunique())
Float32
False
```

Comment: This site is not a tutoring service, it is best used when you have a specific problem with written code. Your question, reads like "Can someone provide me with a tutorial on how to code this works,  which are off-topic for Stackoverflow. Please take the [tour], read [what are you asking].

Answer (score 1):

You can read the [source](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v2.1.0/pandas/core/tools/numeric.py#L42-L317) of [`pd.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html). The code responsible to downcast is [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/ba1cccd19da778f0c3a7d6a885685da16a072870/pandas/core/tools/numeric.py#L245-L273)

The key is:

```
>>> np.typecodes["Float"]
'efdg'
```

From the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.scalars.html#floating-point-types), letters stand for:

- e (half): `float16`
- f (single): `float32`
- d (double): `float64`
- g (longdouble): `float128`

The algorithm is to try dtype from the smallest to the largest.

**Update**

> I do not see where the condition being used to select a particular dtype

And yet it's all there. The code resolution looks like:

```
from pandas.core.dtypes.cast import maybe_downcast_numeric
from pandas.core.arrays import FloatingArray

# L179
values = s.values  # extract numpy array
typecodes = np.typecodes["Float"]  # downcast='float'

# L202
mask = values._mask
values = values._data[~mask]  # convert pd.Float64 to np.float64

# L260
# remove float16 from possible dtypes
float_32_char = np.dtype(np.float32).char
float_32_ind = typecodes.index(float_32_char)
typecodes = typecodes[float_32_ind:]

# L264
for typecode in typecodes: # for f, d and g
    dtype = np.dtype(typecode)  # convert as dtype
    if dtype.itemsize <= values.dtype.itemsize:
        values = maybe_downcast_numeric(values, dtype)
# 1st iteration 'f': values are downcast to float32
# 2nd iteration 'd': no downcast because values is now float32
# 3rt iteration 'g': no downcast because values is now float32

# L284
data = np.zeros(mask.shape, dtype=values.dtype)

# L300
klass = FloatingArray
values = klass(data, mask)  # convert np.float32 to pd.Float32
```

Output:

```
>>> values
<FloatingArray>
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
 ...
 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
Length: 100000, dtype: Float32
```

Comment: I saw that code, but I do not see where the condition being used to select a particular dtype

Comment: @KGinChicago. I updated my answer, can you check it ?